# Ajax fetch variable to php to select from SQL

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So I need to pass variable to my "fetch" php, on `fetch.php` I make query to mysql DB with given parameters.

And now I am stuck..

I am able to fetch variable like so :

```
data: {
    "Kood":'<?php echo $params->get('Kood');?>'
},
```

Then I catch it in `fetch.php` and make request to db :

(after some if statements I make sql request)

```
$query .= 'and kood LIKE "%'.$_POST["Kood"]["value"].'%"  ';
```

Everything works almost fine but instead of "Like" I would use Equal, if I change my request to equal then it fails to get any results back..

Example :

```
select * 
from table 
where kood='KERR2018'
```

(btw when I use like then it also gets KERR2019 results somehow..)

and thats how I tried to get "equal" to :

```
$query .= 'and kood ="'.$_POST["Kood"]["value"].'"  ';
```

I feel like, it looses numbers and uses only chars?

When I made var in `fetch.php` (`$Kood="KERR2018";`) then it worked as I wanted..

Comment: So this post has nothing to do with AJAX?

Comment: Have you check that you have value in $_POST["Kood"]["value"]?

Comment: god damn, $_POST["Kood"]["value"] it gives only first letter from actual :O ( gives only "K" from "KERR2018"

Comment: 1/ Is your request working when you write it by hand? 2/ Is your request looks like you want if you do `echo $query;` ? 3/ What do you get if you do `var_dump($_POST["Kood"]["value"])`?

Comment: No offense, but why do you post a question if you didn't try to debug it first? The FIRST reflex when you have a problem is to check if you get the right data in the right place, no? `var_dump()`, `print_r`, `echo`, `console.log()` or other function to display data are here for this :)

Comment: i did some debuging, and i seem to be stupid enough. 

Long story short, i am wrong at passing string to fetch.php

data: {
    "Kood":'<?php echo $params->get('Kood');?>'
},

so this is the place where i am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query .= 'and kood ="'.$_POST["Kood"]["value"].'"  ';
```

was wrong aproach. 
should be without "value"

```
$query .= 'and kood ="'.$_POST["Kood"].'"  ';
```